# Misplacement of info in rows in tables in Boostrap

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, row

I have a responsive bootstrap table and some of the info that I generate from PHP doesn't sit correctly in the row. Here is a link to my screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The PHP code, which generates the table is this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
        echo "<table class='table'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td> " . "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . "</td> " . "<td>". $row["lastname"] ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
} else{ echo "0 results"; }
```

Comment: Sorry for the name of the topic, I couldn't think of a better name.

Comment: You're creating a table for every result. Try putting only the `<tr>` up to `</tr>` inside the loop and move the other lines outside.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your while loop above div which is generating your div and table again and agian.

Insted of this just place your loop after table tag and just before `<tr>`. Then it will only generate your new row insted of div and table.

Your code should be look similar to this:

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    // output data of each row
?>

<div class='table-responsive'>
        <table class='table'>
            <?php
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td> " . "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . "</td> " . "<td>". $row["lastname"] ."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
              ?>
        </table>
    </div>


<?php
} else{ echo "0 results"; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create new `<table>` for every row. Instead you should create separate `<tr>` for each record. You can also use `<tbody>` which is part of standard for using tables:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
    echo "<table class='table'><tbody>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td> " . "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . "</td> " . "<td>". $row["lastname"] ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
    echo "</div>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
```

You've had different sizes for each record because you had 1 record = 1 table, and width wasn't preserved across different records. Now it's correct.

Comment: Yeah it works now. Apparently it was because i create a new table in the loop every time i generate a new name. Thanks for the help. :) Too bad I cant vote for you because i am new.